# Simple Speech into Text in IPhone

Tags: objective-c, speech-to-text

I am trying to developing the app like speech into text , i want to convert the speech into a text in textfield .I have searched in google i got some sample code but that is not useful.i got these link,[raywenderlinch](https://www.raywenderlich.com/60870/building-ios-app-like-siri),but in this they mentioned some API is used for speech reconginization ,but i cant able to get that.

Please anyone can share a tutorial with the sample project it might be very useful to me .

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: "Find me a tutorial" is not a suitable topic to stackoverflow.

Comment: @ EI Tomato , Please tell  me how to do this , i dont have any knowledge about this

Comment: @AgalSivamanoj In that tutorial they are using "SpeechKit" which is developed by "Nuance Developers". If you couldn't understand or having trouble to understand then you can use "Speech" in your project. For more reference you can use this tutorial "https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/" .

Comment: @unexpextedNil , This link is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

_recognizer = [[SFSpeechRecognizer alloc] initWithLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"]];
[_recognizer setDelegate:self];
[SFSpeechRecognizer requestAuthorization:^(SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatus authStatus) {
    switch (authStatus) {
        case SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            //User gave access to speech recognition
            NSLog(@"Authorized");
            break;

        case SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            //User denied access to speech recognition
            NSLog(@"SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatusDenied");
            break;

        case SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            //Speech recognition restricted on this device
            NSLog(@"SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatusRestricted");
            break;

        case SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            //Speech recognition not yet authorized

            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Default");
            break;
    }
}];

audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
_speechSynthesizer  = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];         
[_speechSynthesizer setDelegate:self];
}


-(void)startRecording
{
[self clearLogs:nil];

NSError * outError;

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&outError];
[audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement error:&outError];
[audioSession setActive:true withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation  error:&outError];

request2 = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];

inputNode = [audioEngine inputNode];

if (request2 == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to created a SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object");
}

if (inputNode == nil) {

    NSLog(@"Unable to created a inputNode object");
}

request2.shouldReportPartialResults = true;

_currentTask = [_recognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest:request2
                delegate:self];

[inputNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:4096 format:[inputNode outputFormatForBus:0] block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer, AVAudioTime *when){
    NSLog(@"Block tap!");

    [request2 appendAudioPCMBuffer:buffer];

}];

    [audioEngine prepare];
    [audioEngine startAndReturnError:&outError];
    NSLog(@"Error %@", outError);
}

- (void)speechRecognitionTask:(SFSpeechRecognitionTask *)task didFinishRecognition:(SFSpeechRecognitionResult *)result {

NSLog(@"speechRecognitionTask:(SFSpeechRecognitionTask *)task didFinishRecognition");
NSString * translatedString = [[[result bestTranscription] formattedString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

[self log:translatedString];

if ([result isFinal]) {
    [audioEngine stop];
    [inputNode removeTapOnBus:0];
    _currentTask = nil;
    request2 = nil;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks , user7306261, one doubt ,where i have to do this code ,and have you used any framework ?

Comment: what is SFSpeechRecognizer , in this ,if i do this ,it is showing error , like  Use of  undecalred identifier SFSpeechRecognizer,Please tell me , how to do this ..

Comment: Hi , it shows an error in  [inputNodeEngine installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:4096 format:
       [inputNodeEngine outputFormatForBus:0] block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer, AVAudioTime *when){      } . i want in objective c.Please help me